# Is there an easy way to obtain Pokérus?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've heard that Pokérus accelerates EV training, but the virus is much rarer than a shiny Pokemon. I searched in the grass for about 3 hours, but for the life of me, I can't find a Pokérus-infected Pokemon.

Is there any way to get it easily or do I really have to get it from someone else?

Comment: Hi, Amo.  I've removed the last section, as we don't really do group or site recommendations as questions.  That said, an answer can easily point you at a group somewhere, but also might be able to tell you how to reliably get it on your own.

Comment: Both my wife and I got a Pokerus infected pokemon in ORAS randomly before we had finished the Delta story, which seemed odd, because I had never found one in any of the previous games. It's probably just a rare coincidence, but it seems almost like the pokerus chance is increased in ORAS.

Comment: I've got it from a wild pokemon in Y after 500+ hours, and it was the first time in my life, and I played every generation. So it's not a viable solution.

Comment: in most of the reddit trading subs, you can easily ask for pokerus.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask for help on several forums, I usually use [Neoseeker](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/49446/).
*Pokerus* is really common in the metagame, so if you post a request asking for an "infected" pokemon you'll get one easily.
Or you can spend a couple of hours with Wonder Trade, it's not rare to recieve an infected pokemon. Several trainers trade infected pokemon to help newbie ones.